# Error uploading file to Alfresco using Java, CmisConstraintException:Conflict

Tags: file-upload, alfresco, opencmis

I am getting an error uploading a file to repository using Java. I am using Alfresco 4.0e.  I am able to connect to the repository, located on Unix server, from my Application, developed in struts, from localhost.

I am using OpenCMIS to connect and upload. When I try to upload a document it gives an error after executing `createDocument(...)`

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.cmisconstraintException:Conflict
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the document already exists.  Can you check the logs on the Alfresco server for detail there?

Comment: Most probable cause indeed.

Comment: Apparently nothing shows up in `alfresco.log` when this happens. What log settings do you recommend to make these details appear?